# Is there a fast way to copy a non byte-aligned array of NxM BITs to a larger array of BITs?

Tags: c, image-processing, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I'd like to copy a 1-bit b/w image to a 1-bit memory buffer.  (e.g. "9" below copied to x=25, y=28)

[image: image buffer]

This means that the memory will start at a non-byte aligned position in the frame buffer and ends on a non-byte aligned bit.

Obviously, one can read and set each pixel with bit shifting operations taking O(MxN) time.

The non-trivial way would be to memory copy partial bytes and carry over remaining bits.

Where can I find a C implementation of this or an example?  This is not the first time someone has faced copying non-byte aligned matrices and arrays.

Comment: It really depends on the specifics of the destination buffer and source data. For small embedded systems (like LCDs) I typically munge my font data to be aligned with the destination buffer so I can just memcpy bytes over. But if that's not possible, there's always pre-shifting your data. But again, without knowing your *exact* issue it's impossible to answer. Show us working code, than we might be able to offer a better approach.

Comment: What are your main limitations, code size, RAM size, execution speed? -- Of course this has been done "a million" times, and I'd try to ask my favorite search engine about early GUI systems, GUI libraries for embedded systems, early games, demo programs for simple systems like 80s home computers, and so on. Some of them have open sources, at least today.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Yes, it's small embedded and LCD (EPD).  Byte aligned copy would force the placement of characters on 8-pixel stops.  Right now I'm copying one BIT at a time which is ~1/4 slower than BYTE at a time.  I'm sure someone (graphics folk?) has done a proper bit-shifted copy routine somewhere.

Comment: @thebusybee Exactly!  there has to be early graphics code that does this shifted buffer copy.  I just couldn't find one with my search keywords.  RAM and speed are the limitations.  Obviously giving a byte to every pixel will solve the issue, but we don't have the required 8x more RAM.  TIA.

Comment: One keyword is "bit block transfer" aka "bitblt" commonly used in the Atari ST and Amiga world. These homecomputers used to have a separated chip, the Blitter, for this. However, the low-cost variants of the ST did this in software, and there are open sources. Unfortunately I don't have any link at hand. -- Oh, and the ST had a1-bit black and white mode with linear addressed screen buffer.